# Exit 1 when until loop is ended

Tags: bash

This is my until loop `bash` script that try to exec an ssh command on remote machine:

```
n=0
until [ ${n} -ge 5 ]
do
   ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@test "mkdir -p /test_dir" && break 
   n=$(($n+1))
   sleep 5
done
```

I want that perform exit 1 when the loop has ended without success.

I found this solution:

```
n=0
until [ ${n} -ge 5 ]
do
   ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@test "mkdir -p /test_dir" && exit 0 
   n=$(($n+1))
   sleep 5
done
exit 1
```

Is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one way.

Another way is to do:

```
until [ "$n" -ge 5 ] && exit 1; do
  ... && break
done
echo OK
exit 0
```

Or:

```
while [ "$n" -lt 5 ] || exit; do
  ... && break
done
```

Though here, it looks like you want to repeat the `ssh` command until it succeeds, and abort after so many attempt, so:

```
n=5
until
  ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@test "mkdir -p /test_dir"
do
  n=$((n - 1))
  if [ "$n" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 giving up
    exit 1
  fi
done

echo OK
exit 0
```

Would make more sense.

Comment: I was going to suggest something along the lines of your last example. +1 for that

Answer (score -1):

If you are classifying the loop ending "without success" as when the loop finishes looping then yes, there will be an exit code of 1 when this happens.

The script you've written just finishes with an exit code of 1. If it loops forever then you obviously never get an exit code of 1.

All the exit code does is tell you the success of the last run command.

If the script in your post finishes looping and ends, try running this immediately afterwards:

```
echo $?
```

Then run `echo $?` again. What do you see?
Why do you think it changed?
You probably got it by now: the fact that you ran a sucessful command (in this case `echo`, it could have been almost anything) made the exit state change to zero.

Comment: "Then run `echo $?` again". The output would always be zero if you run `echo $?` again after already running `echo $?` earlier.

Comment: That's the point of my answer. Try reading it properly. The first 'echo $?' displays the exit code from the script (1) and the second 'echo $?' displays the exit code from the first 'echo $?'. Read my answer properly and you'll see.